# Querying data with type not supported by Trino

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, trino

I use Trino to consume data from a MariaDB table.

I have a specificy column at this table with Geographical Data (Point Data https://mariadb.com/kb/en/geometry-types/). Querying the source, the data appear like this:

```
SELECT location FROM x.y.z
```

```
location                   
---------------------------
POINT (51.566682 83.32865) 
POINT (46.77708 16.32856)  
POINT (84.857691 4.295681)
```

But this kind of data isn't supported by Trino (https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/mariadb.html)

I just want the values (x, y) inside POINT(x,y).

The documentation has a flag `unsupported-type-handling=CONVERT_TO_VARCHAR` but when I use it the data retrieved came like this:

```
location                 
-------------------------
         �Q�GHJk ���*@
         �{���GMg'���(@
         0�Z¶nK@�B< / @
```

I tested a lot of conversions on this varchar but no one worked well. So how can I get this kind of data type using Trino?

Answer (score 0):

The datype is not text, so converting it will not help

You can always use natve functions to myriadb, as long as they return datatypes that are allowed

> Table functions

> The connector provides specific table functions to access MariaDB.
> query(varchar) -> table#

> The query function allows you to query the underlying database directly. It requires syntax native to MariaDB, because the full query is pushed down and processed in MariaDB. This can be useful for accessing native features which are not available in Trino or for improving query performance in situations where running a query natively may be faster.

so a query like will work

```
SELECT
  X,Y
FROM
  TABLE(
    mariadb.system.query(
      query => 'SELECT
        ST_X(loacation) as X,
        ST_Y/location) As Y
      FROM
        mytable'
    )
  );
```

Comment: According to the output of `SELECT location ...` the data type is not GEOMETRY.

Comment: that is why i added the last sentence

Comment: The data is not text type on the source but geo type (not supported by MariaDB connector), so to consume it on Trino I used `unsupported-type-handling=CONVERT_TO_VARCHAR`, and now is this ugly varchar that IDK how to convert back to POINT. The limitation here maybe is the connector.

Comment: @AntônioRodrigues i changed my answer, try the new approach